# Go to another activity before inserting from gallery

Tags: android

Maybe its asked before But I couldn't find it in the question.
Anyway I am able to insert an image from gallery. what I want is before inserting the image , I want to go to another activity and let the user to add descriptions then insert the image( like Instagram when inserting image, when uploading an image it takes you to activity to insert details)

This is my code:

```
public   void openGallery() {
    //  Intent gallery =   new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
      //   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      //startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);

      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setType("image/*");
      intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
      intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
      intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
      intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
      intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
      intent.putExtra("outputY", 150);
      intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
      startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"),2);
   }


       @Override
       protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
          Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
          DBhelper db = new DBhelper(this);
          if (extras2 != null) {
           Bitmap yourImage = extras2.getParcelable("data");
           // convert bitmap to byte
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           yourImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
           byte imageInByte[] = stream.toByteArray();
           Log.e("output before conversion", imageInByte.toString());
           // Inserting Contacts
           Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
           db.addContact(new Contact("Android", imageInByte));
           Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
             MainActivity.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();
          }
       }
```

Note : The above code lets you to insert image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Intent to travel to the description page and on filling the description when the user clicks the submits the details, then again using the intent make them travel to select image options.

Comment: Is that simple ? If i get bak to main activty how i continue to insert the image?

Comment: same as the previous one...because every time you get to the main activity the previous is killed, and if you want to get back to it, it will create that activity/process again.

Comment: Ah you mean i insert the image in the second activity .. okay ill try that thanks